# Symfony form binding issue: empty array

Tags: forms, binding, symfony1

i have some difficulties in understanding why my symfony form doesn't bind properly with the data from request...

The action:

```
public function executeSendEmail(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
      $history_id = $request->getParameter('id');

      if($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST))
      {
            print_r("POST");

            $this->form = new SendEmailForm();

            $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('email_form'));
            print_r($request->getParameter('email_form'));

            if(!$this->form->isBound())
                    die('!isBound()');

            print_r($this->form->getValues());

            if($this->form->isValid())
            {
                die('form is Valid!');
            }
            die('after isValid...');
      }

      die('redirect !');

      $this->redirect('history/show?id='.$history_id);
  }
```

Form class:

```
class SendEmailForm extends sfForm
{
   public function setup()
   {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'author'  => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'email'   => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'subject' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'body'    => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(),
    ));

    $this->setValidator('email', new sfValidatorEmail());


    $this->widgetSchema->setLabels(array(
          'author'  =>  'Autor',
          'email'   =>  'E-mail',
          'subject' =>  'Tytuł',
          'body'    =>  'Treść wiadomości'
    ));

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('email_form[%s]');

    $this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);

    parent::setup();
   }
}
```

When entering the action the `$request->getParameter('email_form')` contains:

```
Array ( 
        [author] => RRr 
        [email] => rr@rrr.com 
        [subject] => rrrr 
        [body] => rrrr 
        [_csrf_token] => 73881c1b6217e221c4d25c065ec93052 )
```

so it look correct but nevertheless binding fails because `$this->form->getValues()` returns empty array() and i don't know why ;s ?!
Any suggestions ?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `getValues()` **after** you checked the form is valid. Otherwise in will return an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

You can test to see what the errors are like this:

```
  if($this->form->hasErrors())
  {
    echo $this->form->renderGlobalErrors();
  }
```

If you're generating a form yourself, rather than using the Symfony helper, you might not have included / disabled the csrf token.

Answer (score 1):

Your form class seems fine.

Try this in your action:

```
$this->form = new SendEmailForm();
if($request->isMethod('post')) 
{
    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('email_form'));
    if($this->form->isValid()) 
    {
        $values = $this->form->getValues();
        var_dump($values['author']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bind()` method is doing something like below, so if your form is not valid, you will get an empty array.

```
try
{
  $this->doBind(...);
  ...
}
catch (sfValidatorErrorSchema $e)
{
  $this->values = array(); //here
  $this->errorSchema = $e;
}
```